# C random number generator making the same number

Tags: c

How do i get the random number generator in c to give me different numbers when ever my function is called.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

printf("%i",num());
printf("%i",num());

}
int num() {
    int MAX = 100;
    srand ( time(NULL));
    int num = rand() % MAX;
    return num;
}
```

No matter how many times i call the num function, it always prints the same number. How do i fix this so the number is different for every call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems when calling srand(time(NULL)) inside rollDice function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570803/problems-when-calling-srandtimenull-inside-rolldice-function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `time` function typically returns the time in second resolution, which means that if you call `time(NULL)` twice within one second then you will get the same result.

That will of course mean that you set the same starting seed to the random-number generator, which means the sequence will be the same.

You typically only call `srand` *once*, early in the `main` function.

Answer (score 4):

Move

```
srand ( time(NULL));
```

to `main()` . You need to call `srand()` once in `main()` and keep calling `rand()`

Comment: Expanding on this... you're re-seeding the random number generator with the same value with each of your calls because relative to code execution, the value of `time()` does not change very often. By moving the seeding to happen only once, you eliminate this issue.

Comment: Also, you should only seed a random number object once in a program as a "best practice". I am sure there are exceptions, but I can't think of any.